# Async Task in Application OnCreate

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I plan to make a webservice call in Application onCreate using a asyncTask. The data which the webservice will get will be used in activities later. Since it is a asyncTask there is a chance that it may not complete while the activity wants to use the data. I plan to give some visual feedback to show progress of the data download.

Is there any problem with this whole approach?

Comment: better you call it in launch screen and you can show progress there like we see in most of the app specially game application

Comment: Why don't you try it and get back to us when an actual problem happens :)

Comment: Well I have tried and it works. I still have to do the visual feedback work but other than that things seem to work. I just want to be sure that I am not missing something.

Comment: Use a service for this. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html It's loosly coopled and probably best practice in your case